# Can I re-invite Clan Members after they are kicked out?

Tags: clash-of-clans

One of our members abused the power of co-leading: he kicked everyone and then he left.

Is there any way to be able to reinvite the clan members that were kicked out?

Comment: Once their gone and their last message is not in the clan chat it is not possible to get members back.

Comment: Yeah there gone in the chat box how csn I get them back

Comment: You can't. You won't find them in global either because there is more than 100 global chat rooms.

Comment: Ok I will just let other players join than wasting 30 mins trying to get them back

Answer (score 1):

1. The new thing- there are 8-letter/digit things on the player profile (known as player tag). Write those on a piece of paper next time and then if you've the privilege to invite then invite them back.
2. Add them as your friend. You can also do that after the new update October 2016 update. If a player is your friend (After he/she accepts your friend request or is your friend through Facebook) and you have the privilege to invite then you can invite that player even if he/she has already joined another clan.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no way. Unless they are still in the clan chat section (I know they are not, because of your comment). However, make all the things needed to join the clan (trophy level, etc.) low. If your members want to join again, they can, even if they are farming, or have a low trophy count. You can try global chat, but the chances for you 1) being in the same chat room and 2) the other person happening to be on global is very low.

I think the situation of a co-leader kicking everyone out happens to everyone. It has happened to me. It teaches you the lesson that hey, make sure someone is VERY trustworthy before you make them co-leader. Even then, you can never be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can invite the players in certain situation. First of all you have to reach their profile in clan chat or in clan war map or in mail. If you found them and they does not have clan then you can invite them. Else you can't.

Answer (score 0):

If the message that said that they where kicked out is still in the chat log, then tap that and tap invite to invite them back.

Comment: so there is a way